Antiderivative and basic integration for a logistic function?
I need to find the antiderivative of the logistic function of the form $3/(1+e^{-3.302(x-26)})+1.2$ so I can apply a definite integral to it. I apologise for any mistakes or things that don't apply, I am new to this. I believe I'm supposed to try substitution in which I define $x$ as $g(t)$ such that $dx/dt=g'(t)$ so $dx=g'(t)dt$ which leaves me with the equation $\int f(g(t))g'(t)dt$ so the function becomes $3/(1+e^{-3.302(g(x)-26)})+1.2$
After this, I realised maybe I should have just applied the basic rules to each individual term? Is that what I should do or should I continue with substitution?
From here I understand I need to find the indefinite integral and several sources told me I should define dx but not really explained how, so how does one go about this?
Thanks so much for any help!

This website uses MathJax to display math symbols. Here is a tutorial on how to use it:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Wolfram Alfa gives: $\int \frac{3}{1+\exp (-a (x-b))} , dx=-\frac{3 \ln \left(e^{a (b-x)}\right)}{a}+\frac{3 \ln\left(a+a e^{a (b-x)}\right)}{a}+C$

Hint
Replacing numbers by letters, the main problem is to compute
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{1+e^{b-a x}}$$
$$a x-b=t \implies x=\frac{b+t}{a}\implies  dx=\frac {dt} a$$ which make
$$I=\frac 1 a \int \frac{dt}{1+e^{-t}}=\frac 1 a \int \frac{e^t }{e^{t}+1}\,dt=\frac 1 a\int \frac{(e^t+1)' }{e^{t}+1}$$ which is more than simple
